# How to renew kerbors ticket of other user as an admin or root?

Tags: kerberos

How to renew kerbors ticket of other user as an admin or root?
I have some lsf job running which accesses Kerberos protected mount.
As an admin I want to renew Kerberos tickets for this users

Comment: What operating system (since the particular approach will vary)? However, in general you either execute -- by becoming the user -- a "kinit -R" to request the renewal, or the user can setup a keytab file, and then (again, by becoming the user) execute a kinit and specify the keytab.

Comment: Why doesn't the job create its own "private" Kerberos ticket _(by setting a random `KRB5CCNAME` env var)_ on startup, based on a keytab file, then destroy its ticket on completion?

Comment: We are using rhel 6

Comment: Is it possible to renew this from root for all users.either want to create daily new ticket or use existing ticket with renew untill till time to be increased by a day

Comment: For the record, if your Linux box used Kerberos authentication via SSSD (or Centrify etc.) then you could require the ticket to be renewed automatically. If Kerberos is just used to authenticate to a third-party system (such as Hadoop or a web service), then a DIY solution is required.

Comment: How about create a keytab for that user?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You have to execute kinit command as the user you want to authenticate. It will create a ticket cache for that particular user only.

Purpose of your requirement is not clear. If you want to kinit periodically, you can use "crontab".

Comment: Objection: technically _root_ could run a `kinit` for any Kerberos principal (as long as the appropriate keytab file is available somewhere); it could use the ticket cache of any Linux user (by setting `$KRB5CCNAME` to match the default cache file for the user before `kinit` then granting access to that file afterwards).

Comment: Ok for that, First you have to kinit with root. Then you have to set $KRB5CCNAME and $KRBTKFILE (generated by kinit from root) for each user while being root. Am I right? If that's possible, It would be the answer for the question.

Comment: Yep, to be tested... (Nit : `KRBTKFILE` was for Kerberos 4, long ago...)

Answer (score 0):

I am presently running a shell script which login to each user form root using "su - username".
I want to change max life time date of Kerberos ticket for each user when ever script is run.
I want max lifetime of kerberos ticket should be 7 days later whenever script is run.
Means if script is run on 1 Dec at 10:30 am then max lifetime should be 8 Dec 10:30 am.